# Pulling a data from a inner join table and merging two rows into one

Tags: sql, oracle

What I want to achieve from query is select all avatars and their father and mother (by getting parentID and gender to determine) and display for each avatar 1 row with avatar username father username mother username.

This is kind of a solution I was thinking about not finished a subquery that returns first father and another subquery for inner join to return mother

```
SELECT avatars.username as ChildUsername, father.username as FatherUsername, mother.username as MotherUsername
FROM avatars
INNER JOIN avatars father(
  SELECT *
  FROM children
  INNER JOIN children child ON 
  WHERE avatars.gender = 'M' AND 
)
INNER JOIN avatars mother
```

Database:

```
CREATE TABLE avatars
    (avatarID NUMBER CONSTRAINT pk_avatars PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR2(20),
    gender CHAR(1)
    );

CREATE TABLE children
    (childID NUMBER CONSTRAINT pk_children PRIMARY KEY,
    childAvatarID NUMBER,
    parentAvatarID NUMBER
    );

ALTER TABLE children
ADD FOREIGN KEY (parentAvatarID)
REFERENCES avatars(avatarID);

ALTER TABLE children
ADD FOREIGN KEY (childAvatarID)
REFERENCES avatars(avatarID);
```

Data:

```
INSERT INTO avatars VALUES (1,'av1','M');
INSERT INTO avatars VALUES (2,'av2','F');
INSERT INTO avatars VALUES (3,'av3','M');

INSERT INTO children VALUES (1,3,1); //Father 
INSERT INTO children VALUES (2,3,2); //Mother
```

for the above data I would want to get this output

```
   ChildUsername FatherUsername MotherUsername
   av3           av1            av2
```

Comment: Your children table has 3 columns and your insert into children has 4 parameters. Are you forgeting any info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to join the avatars table twice - self and parent.

```
select s.username as ChildUsername,
    max(case when p.gender = 'M' then p.username end) as FatherUsername,
    max(case when p.gender = 'F' then p.username end) as MotherUsername,
    max(case when p.gender = 'M' then p.someothercolumn end) as FathersSomeOtherColumn,
    max(case when p.gender = 'F' then p.someothercolumn end) as MothersSomeOtherColumn,
    . . .
from children c
join avatars s on c.childAvatarID = s.avatarId
left join avatars p on c.parentAvatarId = p.avatarId
group by c.childAvatarID,
    s.username;
```

Comment: aww you had two left joins a couple minutes ago, now it just looks like I copied your answer.

Comment: @SqlZim - While editing I realized one was redundant. :-)

Comment: @GurV Cheers, one more thing how could I use  max(case when p.gender = 'M' then p.username end) to get the father avatar so I could display more attributes than just username and so I can inner join that father avatar with other tables?

Comment: @Higeath - You can use case similarly for other column as well. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: @GurV and one more thing what about inner joins for parents?

Comment: @Higeath - A parent record may or may not be present for a child which is why we used left join.

Answer (score 1):

Using conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    av.username
  , max(case when p.gender = 'M' then p.username end) as Father
  , max(case when p.gender = 'F' then p.username end) as Mother
from avatars av
  inner join children c
    on av.avatarid = c.childavatarid
  left join avatars p
    on p.avatarid = c.parentavatarid
group by av.username
```

Comment: @Gurv Woohoo! ty

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would work to select the mothers and fathers as subqueries.

```
SELECT distinct a.username as ChildUsername, f.FatherUsername, m.MotherUsername
FROM avatars a
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT a.username as FatherUsername, c.childAvatarID
  FROM avatars a
  INNER JOIN children c 
  ON a.avatarID = c.parentAvatarID
  WHERE a.gender = 'M'
) f
ON a.avatarID = f.childAvatarID
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT a.username as MotherUsername, c.childAvatarID
  FROM avatars a
  INNER JOIN children c 
  ON a.avatarID = c.parentAvatarID
  WHERE a.gender = 'F'
) m
ON a.avatarID = m.childAvatarID
```